# pyspark dataframe writing csv files twice in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a pyspark dataframe and trying to write the file in s3 bucket in csv format. here the file is writing in csv but the issue is it's writing the file twice(i.e., with actual data and another is with empty data). I have checked the data frame by printing fine only. please suggest any way to prevent that empty wouldn't create.

code snippet:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=dt1, schema = op_df.columns)
df.write.option("header","true").csv("s3://"+ src_bucket_name+"/src/output/"+row.brand +'/'+fileN)
```

Comment: Did you compare the data within those csv files? Is it exactly the same?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to make sure that the output will include only one file is to do `repartition(1)` or `coalesce(1)` before writing.
So something like this:

```
df.repartition(1).write.option("header","true").csv("s3://"+ src_bucket_name+"/src/output/"+row.brand +'/'+fileN)
```

Note that having one partition doesn't not necessarily mean that it will result in one file as this can depend on the `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile` configuration as well. Assuming this config is set to `0` (the default) you should get only 1 file in the output.